# detect duplicates in excel

Tags: excel

I have a customer table in Excel 2003 and need to group reps from the same companies. In the example below, I would like to copy column A to column D if the data in row A is a duplicate.

Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you just use the "sort" function in excel and sort by column A, alphabetical order. Or am I missing something?

Reference: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sort-a-range-HP005202954.aspx

Comment: The issue is we have 16,000 rows and roughly 300 duplicates. If I can copy over the duplicates to D, sorting row D alphabetically would group them all together nicely and save me a ton of time.

Answer (score 0):

In D2 put
`=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)>1,A2,"")`
and copy down to extract all duplicates (but not originals)